# How to check the double list length?

Tags: haskell

How to check the length of list of list?

I'm trying to check the frequency of each numbers using group (sort xs) function.
I think I can use map and length function but have no idea.

```
import Data.List

freqs :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
freqs [] = []
freqs xs = group (sort xs)
```

The output of above code is

Main> freqs [3,2,1,1]

[[1,1],[2],[3]]

But I want to get the frequency of each numbers.
So, the expected output is [2,1,1], 1 occurring twice, 2 occurring once, 3 occurring once.

Comment: What would the input be for `freqs [-1, -1, -1, -2]`? Or `freqs [-1, 1000]`?

Comment: No negative number

Comment: Or [1,3]. -2 occurring once, -1 occurring 3 times.

Comment: But `[1,3]` could also mean `1` occurring once and `2` occurring 3 times, couldn't it? What I am saying is, storing the frequencies in an `[Int]` is not  a good idea. I suggest storing it in a `[(Int, Int)]` or a `Data.Map`.

Comment: Then how could I get [2,1,1] from [[1,1], [2], [3]]?

Comment: What I am saying is it is much more useful to get `[(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 1)]` from `[3, 2, 1, 1]`. Is there any reason why you must use a more ambiguous format like `[2, 1, 1]`?

Comment: Coz marking system is asking it.

Comment: I see. Just for clarification, `freqs [1000]` produces a list with 999 `0`s followed by a `1`?

Comment: yes Main> freqs [1000] produces [1] and freqs [999] produces [1] as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can basically `map` the result you got from `group (sort xs)` with the `length` function, which gets the length of a list.

```
freqs xs = map length $ group $ sort xs
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works so well. Could I ask what does '$' mean? Is it kind of parentheses?

Comment: ($) is the function application but it's right associative and has the lowest priority, on the other hand the function application with the space has the highest priority and it's left-associative. You can use it to get rid of some parentheses (http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#function-application)